# How do we test a HF transformer to see if it steps up correctly?

Tags: transformer, power-electronics, inverter, high-frequency

i have a HF transformer that iv designed and built but i dont know how to test it. The primary resistance is about 0.05 Ohms across the primary and im putting in 12 V. The moment i connect this, the fuse in the Variac blows. What should i do?

- Rpri = 0.05Ohms
- Input voltage  = 12 V
- turns ratio: 2:85

Comment: First you measure the inductance. If you can not do this, you go to digikey/mouser/whatever and buy the transformer you need.

Comment: what's the design frequency, core area, design primary inductance, type of driver you are using (circuit diagram please of everything between the variac and the transformer).

Comment: I know the inductance. Lpri = 0.021uH, Lsec = 33.54uH.

Comment: with a 21nH primary inductance and only 1:40 ratio you will probably  have to use HF to get any useful results.

Comment: DC or AC and what test frequency?

Answer (score 1):

Try a lower test voltage. If it is designed for high frequency and you are trying to test at 50 or 60 Hz, you need to use a lower voltage. Test voltage = design voltage X test frequency / design frequency.

Comment: Thank you very much, but according to that equation, ill have to be testing at 0.01 V (testing a system designed for 12V at 60kHz at 50Hz). Does this sound about right?

Comment: That is right. However, I based that on the assumption that this is an iron core transformer. If it is not, that formula is probably not right. Either way, it appears you will probably have to use HF to get any useful results as Sphero Pefhany wrote.